# how to fix Openshot crashing everytime when making videos longer than 4+ hours?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, video, crash

I am trying to create a video that is longer than 4+ hours using openshot software on Linux and Windows 7. Both test failed miserably. In fact, the whole program completely freezes within 2 minutes of trying to export the video and then it crashes altogether. I've tried closing everything else thinking the program needs all the memory it needs to do this. Still, it didn't work.

Does anyone know why this is and if not are there software out there is PAID and/or FREE that can easily allow you to create videos 4+ hours or longer and export it with no issues?

Any hints or clues will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Only way to resolve this issue was uninstalling the latest and the greatest version of Openshot and installing the OLD version of OpenShot that actually works flawlessly on my machine. That's what I am using now old version of OpenShot and so far, it has not given me any issue at all. I can export a video as long as 6 hours and it does it even though it takes about 9 to 18 hours, which is expected.

Answer (score -1):

Does it crash after you press the "close" button in the prompt where he asks if you wanna wait or does it crash automatically?
as i experienced something similar but not for such a long video. it stuck at overlaid videos and i had to wait like 5 minutes but then it went on.

so, if it does not crash automatically try to let the programm do the job overnight. or you could just try it with a 1h sequence.

Comment: Unfortunately, it simply shuts down itself after being frozen for about 2 minutes automatically. I know what you are talking about where it sometimes freezes, but if you let it go over night or something like that it will eventually get through the whole video. I wish that was the case, but this time around the whole program simply shutdown automatically.